# Limits/partial derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative

Please help me with this question. It's topic on limits and partial derivative.

Find the maximal value of $f(x,y)=xy((1-x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2))^{0.5}$ for $a=74.4$, $b=64.8$. Round off your answer to $4$ decimal places.

Comment: What have you done so far? Is the exponent $ 0.5$ for the last term in the objective fn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to provide hints and you can fill in the details.

- Find the critical points:

A graph shows:

[image]

The critical points are located at:

$(0,0), (-42.95486002770815687948066927, -37.41229744348774954019284098), (42.95486002770815687948066927, 37.41229744348774954019284098), (-42.95486002770815687948066927, 37.41229744348774954019284098), (42.95486002770815687948066927, -37.41229744348774954019284098)$

- Next, find all partials: $f_x, f_y, f_{xx}, f_{yy}, f_{xy}, f_{yx}$
- Using those partials and if possible, classify each of these critical points as a global or local minimum or maximum
- You should arrive at a global max $927.824976598496188596782456$ at two of the points
- You should arrive at a global min $-927.824976598496188596782456$ at two of the points
- The other critical point  cannot be classified

As an additional hint, here is a 3D plot of this function:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Nice work! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Did you see this idea? I love the idea of having professors interacting with the younger students. http://www.proofschool.org/#1

Comment: Awesome! Another "favorited" website! Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment,
but I find it easier to enter math
as an answer:

It seems to me that
it would be easier to work with
$f^2(x,y)=x^2y^2(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2})
$.

Also, is the fact that
this is dealing with
the ellipse
$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}
=1$
of any help?